# Java 1.6 Encode Base64 inputStream of a Excel file byte[] stream

Tags: java, excel, file, base64

I have been searching the web for this particular problem. Maybe I'm doing something wrong or I'm missing something here...

I'm trying to convert a file stream (an Excel file) -> mimetype (application/octet-stream or application/vnd.ms-excel) doesn´t matter...to a Base64 encoded string.

The reason I'm doing this is because I want to provide the file in a REST API inside a JSON object for later decoding in the browser the base64 string and download the file.

When I receive the InputStream and save it to the disk everything works fine...

Even when I use POSTMAN to get the FILE if I save the file it opens in Excel with all the right data.

**THE CODE** -> Used this simple [example](https://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/use-httpurlconnection-to-download-file-from-an-http-url) to download a file from a URL

```
URL url = new URL(fileURL);
HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
//etc...i get response code OK(200) get file name etc

// opens input stream from the HTTP connection
InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();

String saveFilePath1 = "C:\\test1.xlsx";
String saveFilePath2 = "C:\\test2.xlsx";
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFilePath1);
             
int bytesRead = -1;
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {   
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}

//FOR TESTING PURPOSES AT THIS POINT I HAVE SAVED THE STREAM INTO 
//**test1.xlsx** SUCCESSFULLY and opens into excel and everything 
//is fine.

//THE PROBLEM RESIDES HERE IN THIS NEXT PIECE OF CODE
//import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

//I try to encode the string to Base64
String encodedBytesBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64String(buffer);
                
//WHEN I DO THE DECODE AND WRITE THE BYTES into test2.xlsx this file doesn´t work...
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(saveFilePath2); 
byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encodedBytesBase64);
fos.write(bytes);

//Close streams from saved file test2
fos.close();

//Close streams from saved file test1
outputStream.close();
inputStream.close();
```

I even took the string to check if it is a valid Base64 String, which it is accordind to this site -> [Base64 Validator](https://base64.guru/tools/validator)

But when I try to decode the string in the same website it tells me there's a different encoding:

[image]

Is it possible this is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can ignore those warnings. Rather, the issue is here:

```
int bytesRead = -1;
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {   
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
:
String encodedBytesBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64String(buffer);
```

As you can see in the first part, you are reusing `buffer` to read the input stream and write to the output stream. If this loops around more than once, `buffer` will be overwritten with the next chunk of data from the input stream. So, when you are encoding `buffer`, you are only using the last chunk of the file.

The next problem is that when you are encoding, you are encoding the full buffer array, ignoring the `bytesRead`.

One option might be to read the inputStream and write it to a ByteArrayOutputStream, and then encode that.

```
int bytesRead = -1;
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
ByteArrayOutputStream array = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {   
    array.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
String encoded = Base64.encodeBase64String(array.toByteArray());
```

Comment: You are a life saver ...it worked. I don´t even believe how couldn´t I saw that.